# how to add border color to unchecked antd checkbox

Tags: css, antd

I need to add a border color and make the border thicker for antd checkbox.

```
<Checkbox>Add</Checkbox>
```

css:

```
.ant-checkbox-checked .ant-checkbox-inner {
    background-color: red;
    border-color: red;
}
```

The above code helped me changed the checkbox when only 'checked'

I also tried,

```
outline : 2px solid red;
```

How can I change the width and color of the border for a antd checkbox ?

Answer (score 1):

To change the checkbox when **not checked** all you have to do is use:

```
      .ant-checkbox-inner {
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
        border-width: 3px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border-color: red;
      }
```

But to style it while it's **checked**:

```
      .ant-checkbox-checked .ant-checkbox-inner {
        background-color: blue;
        border-color: blue;
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
        font-size: 24px;
      }
```

Comment: this works, but still shows a blue on hover

Comment: To change hover color target the CSS with the :hover pseudo-class

Comment: tried `.ant-checkbox-inner:hover{ color:yellow}` . still gives blue

Answer (score 0):

This was actually pretty hard to change. Here's what worked for me to stop the blue border when hovering:

```
.ant-checkbox-wrapper:hover .ant-checkbox-inner,
.ant-checkbox:hover .ant-checkbox-inner,
.ant-checkbox-input:focus + .ant-checkbox-inner {
  border-color: #cecece !important;
}
```